# GWT, SSL and Glassfish. Is there SSL now?

Tags: gwt, ssl, glassfish

Sorry if this will be too common or simple question but I don't know what should I put into Google to finaly find the answer.

I have GWT application which is now currently running on Glassfish. I can run the application on port 8080 (http) or 8181 (https). The thing is - am I using SSL now?

Default self signed certificate is enough for me for now (I know about keytool and import certificates), I just have to clarify this simple question.

I red here [GWT and SSL not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266127/gwt-and-ssl-not-working) I need to set up security-constraint in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>sslprotect</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Is this enough then? In the comments Sam writes something about "implement the whole usage of SSL correctly."

So question: Is this enough? Is my application SSL protected now?

To be honest, I studied security algorithms on the University but I failed in implementation misserably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough.
 If you can see the **https** in front of your URL, everything is fine. You can check if you are SSL-protected by browsing to the http URL, this should return an error or redirect you to the https URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, there is https and when I try to access standard http, there is Error 403. Then I suppose everything should be ok. Thank you again